# Error while loading image from gallery in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

After selecting an image, the follwing error is displayed:

**LOGCAT:**

```
09-14 16:29:36.788: E/AndroidRuntime(10542): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-14 16:29:36.788: E/AndroidRuntime(10542): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.Aod.finalapp/com.Aod.finalapp.tab.FeaturedActivity}: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.Aod.finalapp.tab.FeaturedActivity$CompaignFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
09-14 16:29:36.788: E/AndroidRuntime(10542):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2062)
09-14 16:29:36.788: E/AndroidRuntime(10542):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2087)
09-14 16:29:36.788: E/AndroidRuntime(10542):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:133)
09-14 16:29:36.788: E/AndroidRuntime(10542):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1198)
09-14 16:29:36.788: E/AndroidRuntime(10542):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-14 16:29:36.788: E/AndroidRuntime(10542):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
09-14 16:29:36.788: E/AndroidRuntime(10542):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4777)
09-14 16:29:36.788: E/AndroidRuntime(10542):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-14 16:29:36.788: E/AndroidRuntime(10542):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-14 16:29:36.788: E/AndroidRuntime(10542):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
09-14 16:29:36.788: E/AndroidRuntime(10542):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
09-14 16:29:36.788: E/AndroidRuntime(10542):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-14 16:29:36.788: E/AndroidRuntime(10542): Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.Aod.finalapp.tab.FeaturedActivity$CompaignFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
09-14 16:29:36.788: E/AndroidRuntime(10542):    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:588)
09-14 16:29:36.788: E/AndroidRuntime(10542):    at android.app.FragmentState.instantiate(Fragment.java:97)
09-14 16:29:36.788: E/AndroidRuntime(10542):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.restoreAllState(FragmentManager.java:1721)
09-14 16:29:36.788: E/AndroidRuntime(10542):    at android.app.Activity.onCreate(Activity.java:883)
09-14 16:29:36.788: E/AndroidRuntime(10542):    at com.dobango.finalapp.tab.FeaturedActivity.onCreate(FeaturedActivity.java:243)
09-14 16:29:36.788: E/AndroidRuntime(10542):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
09-14 16:29:36.788: E/AndroidRuntime(10542):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
09-14 16:29:36.788: E/AndroidRuntime(10542):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2026)
09-14 16:29:36.788: E/AndroidRuntime(10542):    ... 11 more
09-14 16:29:36.788: E/AndroidRuntime(10542): Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.dobango.finalapp.tab.FeaturedActivity$CompaignFragment; no empty constructor
09-14 16:29:36.788: E/AndroidRuntime(10542):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
09-14 16:29:36.788: E/AndroidRuntime(10542):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
09-14 16:29:36.788: E/AndroidRuntime(10542):    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:577)
09-14 16:29:36.788: E/AndroidRuntime(10542):    ... 18 more
```

**Code:**

*Created Constructor:*

```
public class CompaignFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener, OnKeyListener,OnTabChangeListener  {

    public CompaignFragment(Context context) {
        // Empty constructor required for fragment subclasses
        context=context;
    }

    public CompaignFragment()
    {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    }
}
```

*Selecting from Gallery:*

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
```

Comment: put your code here..

Comment: Do you have a public default constructor in CompaignFragment class? It should look like public CompaignFragment() {}

Comment: YES, tried with that also...not working

Comment: How do you load image from gallery? Can you post your code?

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent();
                       intent.setType("image/*");
                       intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                       startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                               "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,non static inner class cant instantiated...two ways solve this

1. using Static Class( But all member should be static)
2. other way create new class(Best way)

Answer (score 0):

Your fragment class seems to be a non-static inner class of `FeaturedActivity`. Thus it cannot be instantiated outside of the activity class scope. Adding `static` to your `CompaignFragment` class definition might help:

```
public static class CompaignFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener, OnKeyListener,OnTabChangeListener  {
// rest of your code here..
}
```

Or consider moving the class to upper level (a file of it's own).